# Share project.json attributes between many projects

Tags: asp.net-core

In a solution that contains many ASP.NET 5 class library projects, how do I share a single project.json file between those projects?

The following fields are the same for all project.json files in my solution:

- version
- authors
- projectUrl
- licenseUrl
- copyright

Is there a way to set these fields once for all projects?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built-in solution for that.

`project.json` files are fully static, non-declarative.

There is a related [request](http://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3173) on github. Currently, it seems they won't add a similar feature in a short time.